# Multiplex usage of I/O pins: PWM pulse output + UART

Tags: stm32, arm, multiplexer, gpio

I have the problem, that I have a device with limited output pins and want to know if it is possible to implement a multiple pin usage with additional HW/SW (time multiplexed mode).

In my case my device is a flow meter (based on an ARM Cortex M0 STM32L051) and has by default a pulse output on two pins (which are intented to transmit a PWM signal in push-pull mode via the I/O driver: iC-Haus iC-DXC3).

The other usage I want to overlay these two pins is for a UART communication (RX/TX). Just for the case of service use, like firmware upgrade.
The UART functionality should be only available just after boot the device for a short time slice (e.g. 5 seconds). After that period the pin shall switch in the pulse output mode until the next reboot.

Can someone please explain me, if this would be possible in general and if yes perhaps give some hints how that could be realized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a resistor between CFO and NIN to use the UART and speak half-duplex serial on the OUT pin of the iC-DXC3.

Use OE to control direction (high to send, low to receive) 
send normal UART data on the NIN pin

To receive configure the pin connected to NIN as an input with a weak pull-up, and set OE low.  Now the data received and presented on OUT and mirrored on CFO will be presented on via the resistor onto NIN where it can be read.

Unless you have a UART capable of single-pin half-duplex operation you will need to communicate in one of the directions using a sofware uart emulation.  sending is by-far the easiest option to implement in software.

If on the other hand you want to make internal connections for your UART you can do that too. but be aware that during UART operation the out-pin of the iC-DXC3 will be sending some mix of the transmitted and received signals.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! When you read the datasheet and user guide of your STM32, you'll notice that all the output pins serve several functionalities, which are configured by setting some register to the appropriate value.

Your firmware does that somewhere to put the pins to the right output mode and "connect" the PWM (timer) module to them.

You just do the same, but with UART, after boot.

Note that basically all STM32 chips *already* come with a bootloader, which you can enable, that allows you to load firmware across a serial bus, before the regular firmware boots. So you probably don't even have to implement anything, just enable that bootloader by using the BOOT0 pin of your STM32. *Read the manual!* (RTFM)